# How can I write a non-breaking space?

Tags: keyboard, special-characters

Some word processing programs have a menu for entering special characters, including non-breaking spaces.  It is also possible to copy the character created in the word processing program and paste it into other places, such as a terminal or a website text field.  However, it is inconvenient to need to use a word processing program just to generate a non-breaking space in the first place.

How can I use my keyboard directly to enter a non-breaking space?

Comment: In what? A webpage, terminal...?

Comment: On github, for instance.

Comment: Just stick it to the last letter like most languages do ;-)

Comment: Oooh that's so helpful, thanks, I did not think of that /irony

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about entering text in webpages...

Comment: So ? Would it be different in a terminal ? And BTW, wouldn't it be different on other OSes ?

Comment: Do you mean you would leave a space there as in French orthography? It should then be a narrow space (espace fine insécable), and it is debatable whether a normal space there is worse than no space. Anyway, typing of characters depends on the software used (including keyboard driver, though no-break space is usually handled at a higher level).

Comment: @jasonwryan : sorry, your answer is actually helpful, since there should be no narrow space before question marks in english. It is a french habit of mine. Still asking the question though, for science. How would you write a narrow space with firefox in github, SO or reddit? <-- no space, I'm learning.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela : I'd still like to leave a space there when writing in french.

Comment: Well, it assumes those websites allow a restricted range of HTML or markdown in their forms. The short answer is it isn't reliably possible... Testing&nbsp;?

Comment: @jasonwryan : The &nbsp; trick seems to work in SO questions and on github, thanks!

Comment: Yes: I just edited into your question (worked) and my comment (didn't). It will depend on how the site admins scrub content before posting...

Comment: rolling back since it makes the question strange. But you can answer that, I'll accept the answer.

Comment: I'd prefer not to. Glad you got an answer but it is still OT here... :)

Comment: Well, here your solution is to use an html entity, but what about the utf8 character? Wouldn't it also solve the problem? And isn't it an OS-specific problem?

Comment: @jasonwryan After reading both answers, does this still look off-topic to you ?

Comment: @jasonwryan : please admit your mistake and vote to reopen this.

Comment: I have to agree with @greg0ire: the reason why he needs an unbreakable space is not that relevant, it's about keyboard input.

Comment: @jasonwryan, how about now?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Once upon a time I told my Debian fairy that I want `Compose` instead of `Caps Lock` and typing <kbd>Compose</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> now gives me the super solid unbreakable space:

compose space space ! compose space space ! compose space space ! compose space space ! compose space space ! compose space space ! compose space space ! compose space space !

For debianish systems have a look into `/etc/default/keyboard`, I have the following assigment there: `XKBOPTIONS="compose:caps"`.

Alternatively, if you're using KDE, the "advanced" tab, of the `kcmshell4 kcm_keyboard` command lets you configure what key to map to compose.

This setting affects the text terminals too... at least in debian...

Comment: Didn't work for me, probably because I need to restart my session, but the workaround I edited in your question allows me to use compose, and `compose space space` does work! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I know it may be a matter of layout, but I just discovered that on Ubuntu I can just press right Alt and space and it seems that this way I can easily insert non-braking space. Thank You, Your answer helped me discover that I believe!

Answer (score 9):

Try Shift-space. If this doesn't work with your configuration, you can modify it by specifying

```
key <SPCE> { [ space, nobreakspace ] };
```

in XKB symbol settings.

[My explanations on how to change XKB settings](https://www.vinc17.net/unix/xkb.html).

Note also that applications should not do line breaking under certain conditions, such as before a question mark, even after a normal space (as described in the [Unicode Line Breaking Algorithm](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr14/)), so that the non-breaking space could be unnecessary; unfortunately, most applications do not follow this behavior. The non-breaking space U+00A0 is just an explicit non-breaking space; it doesn't mean that a normal space character is always breaking.

Comment: Looks nice, I won't try it right now, but +1

Comment: There shouldn’t be a need to make a custom mapping for `<SPCE>`.  Setxkbmap has [several options](https://www.mankier.com/7/xkeyboard-config) for producing non-breaking space with the spacebar.  For example, non-breaking space on `Shift+Space` on standard US layout: `setxkbmap -option nbsp:level2 us`.